# Overriding static UIApplicationShortcutItems

Tags: ios, 3dtouch, quickaction

I am trying to set up quick actions for my app. I am able to create them either staticly or dynamically.

We have on the fly language change and the quick actions should match the language set in the app. With dynamic quick actions that is easy.

What I'm trying to do is to have quick actions available before the app is launched for the first time. That means also configuring static actions.

**Question:** 
Is there a way to first have static quick actions and then replace them with dynamic ones? Right now it seems to append first static action, because we have only three dynamic action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no way to do it at this moment. From documentation:

> Within this limit, the system shows your static quick actions first,
>   starting at the topmost position in the menu. If your static items do
>   not exhaust the limit and you have also defined dynamic quick actions,
>   then one or more of your dynamic quick actions is displayed.